# Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-facebook4': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

When I'm trying to install the facebook plugin in the ionic

> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable
>   APP_ID="xxxxxxxx" --variable APP_NAME="fblogin"

then it's throwing an error as

```
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-facebook4': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:        \product\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
    at Object.parseElementtreeSync (D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\node        _modules\cordova-common\src\util\xml-helpers.js:180:27)
    at new AndroidManifest (D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\lib\AndroidM        anifest.js:29:20)
    at AndroidProject.getPackageName (D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\li        b\AndroidProject.js:99:12)
    at Api.addPlugin (D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js:223:57)
    at handleInstall (C:\Users\hi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-        lib\src\plugman\install.js:594:10)
    at C:\Users\hi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman        \install.js:357:28
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\hi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:854:        54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\hi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modu        les\q\q.js:883:30)
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\product\project-1\frontend\platforms\android\Android        Manifest.xml'
```

I've tried installing it on the Android platform v6.4 & v7.1.1. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the permissions on the folder, tried with administrator privileges? Maybe its just a permission problem.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: What is the OS you are using? if is a unix you can try with " sudo ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="xxxxxxxx" --variable APP_NAME="fblogin" ", if you are in windows try to open CMD as administrator

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with the build, permission or otherwise. Try the following

- Remove the platform with the command

  ```
  ionic cordova platform rm android
  ```
- Ensure you have the right permissions

  ```
  chmod 700 <your-directory>
  ```
- Add the plugin followed by adding the platform

  ```
  ionic cordova platform add android
  ```
- Add the plugin